# Derived set is closed

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A\subseteq X$.

(*) I want to prove that if for every $x\in \overline A$, $\operatorname{der}(\{x\})$ is closed, then $\operatorname{der}(A)$ is  closed, or equivalently, $\operatorname{der}(\operatorname{der}(A))\subseteq \operatorname{der}(A)$.

I already proved the following statements:

(a) If $\operatorname{der}(\{x\})$ is closed and $x\in \operatorname{der}(\operatorname{der} (A))$ then $x\in \operatorname{der}(A)$.

(b) If for every $x\in\overline A$ we have that $\{x\}$ is closed, then $\operatorname{der}(\operatorname{der}(A))\subseteq\operatorname{der}(A)$.

Can we show that $\operatorname{der}(\{x\})$ is closed implies $\{x\}$ is closed? Maybe it doesn't work... Any hint? Thank you.

Comment: @AymanHourieh, I don't understand it well... $der(A)$ is not always a closed subset.

Comment: @Talexius: can you give an example where $der(A)$ is not closed? Ayman Houreih's answer seems to work in general.

Comment: $X=\{a,b\}$ and $\tau =\{\emptyset, X\}$. Then $der(\{a\})=\{b\}$ is not closed.

Comment: @Talexius: agreed!

Comment: @AymanHourieh: it looks like your answer is not quite right, as Talexius's example shows.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Yes, you are right. I think that question had additional assumptions stated in (now deleted) comments. I remember that there was a lot of back and forth on it. I'll edit my answer to clarify. My proof holds in a $T_1$ space.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\operatorname{der}(\{x\})$ is closed and $x\in \operatorname{der}(\operatorname{der}(A))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503952/operatornameder-x-is-closed-and-x-in-operatornameder-operatorname)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd like to remark that $\operatorname{der}(\{x\})$ may be closed even when singletons are not. The coarse topology on a set with more than one point is an example where this happens. However, with a), you are almost done. Use the fact that for any set $B$ we have $\overline{B}=B\cup \operatorname{der}(B)$. Thus, setting $B=\operatorname{der}(A)$, we have $\overline{\operatorname{der}(A)}=\operatorname{der}(A)\cup \operatorname{der}(\operatorname{der}(A))$ which equals $\operatorname{der}(A)$ by your statement a). Thus $\operatorname{der}(A)$ is equal to its closure and is closed.

Comment: How you conclude that $\overline{der(A)}\subseteq der(A)$?

Comment: Because $\overline{der(A)}=der(A)\cup der(der A)$ and you showed that $der(der A)\subset der A$.

Comment: @Talexius: I edited to make it a little clearer.

Comment: we have by hypothesis (*) that for every $x\in\overline{A}$, $der(\{x\})$ is closed. Is it true that $x\in der(der(A))$ implies that $x\in\overline A$?

Comment: Yes, because you showed $der(der(A))\subset der(A)$ and we know that $der(A)\subset \overline{A}$.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding which part of the argument you don't follow.

Comment: Because I haven't showed that $der(der(A))\subseteq der(A)$. Where do you think I showed that? (I showed that assuming (b), but we need $\{x\}$ is closed for every $x\in\overline A$)

Comment: @Talexius: In your question, you state that you've "already proved" (a), which implies that $der(der(A))\subset der (A)$. Are you saying you only proved "(b) implies (a)"?

Comment: I'm sorry, you were right! In fact, I haven't proved a) yet but we can use it to prove the another problem... Now, I want to prove a), but probably I have to open another thread for that... Thank you very much!