# $\operatorname{der}(\{x\})$ is closed and $x\in \operatorname{der}(\operatorname{der}(A))$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A\subseteq X$.

I have to prove that if $\operatorname{der}(\{x\})$ is closed and $x\in \operatorname{der}(\operatorname{der}(A))$ then $x\in\operatorname{der}(A)$.

I tried this... if $x\notin \operatorname{der}(A)$, there exists an open set $U$ with $x\in U$ such that $U\cap A=\emptyset$.
We know that $x\in X\setminus \operatorname{der} (\{x\})$ and this is open, then $x\in U\cap (X\setminus \operatorname{der}\{x\})$ and this is open. Maybe this will imply a contradiction... What do you think?

Edit: We recall that $\operatorname{der}(A)$ denotes the set of accumulation points of $A$ (some people say "limit point" instead "accumulation point")

Thanks.

Comment: Advice: explain what is meant by 'der'. Not everyone here is familiar with 'der'. I am the living proof of that fact.

Comment: @drhab: $\operatorname{der}(A)$ is probably the [derived set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_%28mathematics%29) of $A$, i.e., the set of limit points of $A$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. Thank you. I am Dutch. Maybe that explains my ignorance.

Comment: @drhab You are not alone. I am a native English speaker and have completed a course in point-set topology, and I had no idea that 'der' was used to describe the set of limit points until now.

Comment: Usually, the notion $A'$ or $A^d$ is used, but the user already used the $der$ is their previous question.

Comment: @Potato "weer wat geleerd..." (Dutch for: 'again I learned something')

Comment: @drhab: I don’t think that I’d seen the notation $\operatorname{der}(A)$ before, but the term *derived set* is familiar; since it matches the abbreviation and fits the context, it was a fairly easy guess. German has *Ableitung (einer Menge)*, which matches the English term, but I can’t find anything but *de verzameling van de ophopingspunten* and the like for Nederlands; is there a special term for that set?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Verzameling van accumulatiepunten. I do not know a Dutch expression that uses only one word.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm late. I'm going to edit it right now.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. I had a look at your profile. Your sympathy for (or should I say 'with'...? No! That is allready in 'sym') 'spreekt boekdelen'. 'Verdichtingspunten' is another one, but you probably allready knew that. In Holland a mathprofessor asks his colleague: 'do you work with fields?' 'No, I stick to 'lichamen', is the answer.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott "afgeleide verzameling" is actually used in Dutch. It's not a common notion to discuss in most courses I have seen. "ophopingspunt" is more commonly used for sequences than for sets. Do you have a Dutch topology text book?

Comment: @Henno: No, I don’t. I’ve occasionally looked at Dutch Wikipedia on the subject, but that’s about it (and I’m much more likely to look at German Wikipedia).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I've got a few Spanish and German elementary topology text books, and  I quite like the German terminology myself. I think Brouwer in the 1920's was almost the last to use Dutch in topology research papers (in journals). Now everything is English except for some stubborn French and Russians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U'$ be an open neighborhood around $x$. As $\text{der}(\{x\})$ is a closed set not containing $x,$ we can choose a smaller open $U\subseteq X-\text{der}(\{x\})$. There is a $y\in U\cap \text{der}(A)$. As $y\notin \text{der}(\{x\}),$ we have a neighbohood $V$ of $y$ not containing $x$, and $V\cap U$ intersects $A.$ So there is a $z\in A\cap U \subseteq A\cap U'$ distinct from $x$. This shows that $x$ is in the derived set of $A$.